# Is it possible to create a wizard in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

Is it possible to create a wizard in Orchard CMS, perhaps by creating a "Wizard" content type which may have optional content parts depending on rules which may assess previous data entered. This may be asking too much. I am just looking into Orchard as a CMS and I can see how it can be some much more ie an application framework.

Many thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 0):

Orchard is just an Mvc application so you may use any tecnique that works on it.

Look at this blog to see a step by step tutorial:
http://afana.me/post/create-wizard-in-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx

You may find useful also this article on how integrate mvc in orchard:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/434484/Welding-on-Orchard-CMS

Have fun...